# Difference between month calculator in salesforce formula field

Tags: formula-field

I have two dates

1. startdate : 12/26/2022
2. enddate : 02-28-2023

if the start date is **1-15th** day then the result should be the current month ex: `mm-dd-yyyy[12-11-2022]` Then December 1st

if the start date is **16th-31st** day then the result should be the current month EX: `mm-dd-yyyy[12-22-2022]` Then January 1st.

if the EndDate  is 1-15th day then the result should be the current month+1 EX: `mm-dd-yyyy[02-11-2022]` Then January 31st

if the EndDate  is 16-31sh day then the result should be the current month+1 EX: `mm-dd-yyyy[02-20-2022]` Then Feb 28th

input **start date result:** December 1st

input **end date result:** Feb 28th

**I am looking for difference in the months from startdate and enddate as per given if conditions**

1. startdate : 12/26/2022
2. enddate : 02-28-2023
   Expected Output/result : [2]

Can we do this in the formula field? I am able to do it in apex it worked but I was unable to do it in the formula field any help would be appreciated.

Formula field i tried:

```
IF(DAY(EndDate__c)  <= 15,(MONTH(EndDate__c)),IF(DAY(EndDate__c)  >= 16,(MONTH(EndDate__c)+1),NULL )) -
IF(DAY(StartDate__c)  <= 15,(MONTH(StartDate__c)),IF(DAY(StartDate__c)  >= 16,(MONTH(StartDate__c)+1),NULL ))
```

Final Output:

```
 ROUND(((IF(DAY(Return_To_Work__c) <= 15, DATE( YEAR(Return_To_Work__c) ,
MONTH(Return_To_Work__c) -1,(DAY(Return_To_Work__c)- 
 DAY(Return_To_Work__c)+
 28 + MOD(((MONTH(Return_To_Work__c) -1) + 
  FLOOR((MONTH(Return_To_Work__c) -1)/8)), 2) + MOD(2, 
  (MONTH(Return_To_Work__c) -1)) + 2 * FLOOR(1/(MONTH(Return_To_Work__c) 
  -1))))
 ,IF(DAY(Return_To_Work__c) >= 16,DATE( YEAR(Return_To_Work__c) 
 ,MONTH(Return_To_Work__c),(DAY(Return_To_Work__c)- 
  DAY(Return_To_Work__c)+28 + MOD(((MONTH(Return_To_Work__c)) + 
    FLOOR((MONTH(Return_To_Work__c))/8)), 2) + MOD(2, 
  (MONTH(Return_To_Work__c))) + 2 * 
   FLOOR(1/(MONTH(Return_To_Work__c))))),NULL)) -
  IF(DAY(First_Day_Of_Leave__c) <= 15, DATE( YEAR(First_Day_Of_Leave__c) 
  , MONTH(First_Day_Of_Leave__c) ,(DAY(First_Day_Of_Leave__c)- 
  DAY(First_Day_Of_Leave__c)+1)),IF(DAY(First_Day_Of_Leave__c) >= 
    16,DATE( YEAR(First_Day_Of_Leave__c) 
  ,MONTH(First_Day_Of_Leave__c)+1,(DAY(First_Day_Of_Leave__c)- 
   DAY(First_Day_Of_Leave__c)+1)),NULL)))/30),0)
```

Comment: What was the result of your formula? Syntax error? Error when on the record page? Unexpected results?

Comment: the result was unexpected  
-9.00.  Insted 3 StartDate is 12/26/2022 enddate: 2/28/2023

Comment: Your question is very confusing.  Are you trying to return 3 values from the formula (start date result, end date result, and Result[3])?  What is Result[3]?  Also your line about Start Date day 15-31 has conflicting info between "current month" and January 1.  Please [edit] your post to clarify everything and include more detail.

Comment: Have David Cheng, sure I will try to be more clear i will edit the post again

Comment: The input field is **StartDate** and **Enddate** based on the conditions it should return an output on the field as number 3

Comment: In addition to @DavidCheng's comment and suggestion, can you clarify why you expected the result to be 3? This makes sense if your output values were 12/1/2022 and 2/28/2023 but not 12/26/2022 and 2/28/2023 (unless you are always "rounding up")

Comment: @bullcitydave Thanks for looking into this i have update the post with the snippet. so that i would be clear what i am expecting out of formula.

Comment: This question seems eerily similar to this recent question from a new person: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/391514/81648

Comment: @Moonpie any suggestion for my update formula If I run the first block and second block separately it is working fine and giving the accurate result. But i need the Month difference between those two blocks

Comment: Thanks Everyone I updated my final output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 ROUND(((IF(DAY(Return_To_Work__c) <= 15, DATE( YEAR(Return_To_Work__c) ,
MONTH(Return_To_Work__c) -1,(DAY(Return_To_Work__c)- 
 DAY(Return_To_Work__c)+
 28 + MOD(((MONTH(Return_To_Work__c) -1) + 
  FLOOR((MONTH(Return_To_Work__c) -1)/8)), 2) + MOD(2, 
  (MONTH(Return_To_Work__c) -1)) + 2 * FLOOR(1/(MONTH(Return_To_Work__c) 
  -1))))
 ,IF(DAY(Return_To_Work__c) >= 16,DATE( YEAR(Return_To_Work__c) 
 ,MONTH(Return_To_Work__c),(DAY(Return_To_Work__c)- 
  DAY(Return_To_Work__c)+28 + MOD(((MONTH(Return_To_Work__c)) + 
    FLOOR((MONTH(Return_To_Work__c))/8)), 2) + MOD(2, 
  (MONTH(Return_To_Work__c))) + 2 * 
   FLOOR(1/(MONTH(Return_To_Work__c))))),NULL)) -
  IF(DAY(First_Day_Of_Leave__c) <= 15, DATE( YEAR(First_Day_Of_Leave__c) 
  , MONTH(First_Day_Of_Leave__c) ,(DAY(First_Day_Of_Leave__c)- 
  DAY(First_Day_Of_Leave__c)+1)),IF(DAY(First_Day_Of_Leave__c) >= 
    16,DATE( YEAR(First_Day_Of_Leave__c) 
  ,MONTH(First_Day_Of_Leave__c)+1,(DAY(First_Day_Of_Leave__c)- 
   DAY(First_Day_Of_Leave__c)+1)),NULL)))/30),0)
```